# Unable to build gRPC ManagedChannel with scala

Tags: java, scala, maven, grpc, grpc-java

I try to create a gRPC client. For

```
val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext(true).build
```

I get this compile time error

```
Error:(18, 87) value build is not a member of ?0
    val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext(true).build
```

gRPC is built for Java. My project is multi-module maven project, where for protobuf files and generated code is in a separate module.

Answer (score 7):

I managed to solve this issue by adding redundant casting

```
 val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder
    .forAddress(host, port)
    .usePlaintext(true)
    .asInstanceOf[ManagedChannelBuilder[_]].build
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try '.build()'? I'm not too familiar with scala but perhaps the parentheses are required for a library written in Java. If it's recognizing up to usePlaintext, then .build() should indeed be valid for the returned ManagedChannelBuilder: http://www.grpc.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#build--